# Flutter GetX Bindings not deleting Controller properly

Tags: flutter, dart, get

I use `GetMaterialApp` and getPages a list with `GetPage`. I cannot grasp how some controllers get deleted and initialized. One of the pages, which is the first one I am implementing this on, is this page:

```
GetPage(
    name: Routes.registration,
    page: () => const RegistrationScreen(),
    binding: RegistrationBindings(),
  ),
```

Where my binding is following:

```
class RegistrationBindings implements Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<ParticipantController>(() => ParticipantController());
    Get.lazyPut<GroupController>(() => GroupController());
    Get.lazyPut<RegistrationController>(() => RegistrationController());
  }
}
```

The RegistrationScreen is a `StatelessWidget` and uses `AppBar`.

When I click to registration view via this button:

```
NavigateButton(
  text: 'Registration',
  icon: Icons.group,
  onPressed: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.registration)
),
```

The controllers are being loaded:

```
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /registration
[GETX] Instance "RegistrationController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "RegistrationController" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "ParticipantController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "ParticipantController" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "GroupController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GroupController" has been initialized
```

But when I press the back button only `ParticipantController` gets deleted:

```
[GETX] CLOSE TO ROUTE /registration
[GETX] "ParticipantController" onDelete() called
[GETX] "ParticipantController" deleted from memory
```

And when I press once again to registration screen. The `ParticipantController` gets initialized and deleted plus the other controllers are being deleted.

```
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /registration
[GETX] Instance "ParticipantController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "ParticipantController" has been initialized
[GETX] "RegistrationController" onDelete() called
[GETX] "RegistrationController" deleted from memory
[GETX] "ParticipantController" onDelete() called
[GETX] "ParticipantController" deleted from memory
[GETX] "GroupController" onDelete() called
[GETX] "GroupController" deleted from memory
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Get.lazyPut() requires `fenix: true` in order to reinitialize the controllers. I changed my bindings to the following and it works flawless (so far).

```
class RegistrationBindings implements Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<ParticipantController>(() => ParticipantController(), fenix: true);
    Get.lazyPut<GroupController>(() => GroupController(), fenix: true);
    Get.lazyPut<RegistrationController>(() => RegistrationController(), fenix: true);
  }
}
```